# check if dictionary contains a Key with some masked chars and get its key value

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I can check if a key is present in a dictionary using .ContainsKey() method. However, I need to find now if a dictionary contains any key that matches only some chars.

```
Dictionary<string, int> myDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
myDict.Add("ABC", 1);
myDict.Add("AAA", 2);
```

So I need to find if the dictionary contains for example any key as `'A*C'`, where `*` means that doesn't care.

Expected result : true.

Then, I need to get the coincidence/s key/s that matches.

Expected result : `"ABC"`.
Maybe Linq is able to do this?

Comment: I'd say a dictionary is the wrong type for this, but if you must, you can probably realize this using a custom key comparer.

Comment: You cannot, in fact, realize this using a custom key comparer, unless you're absolutely sure that the masking never creates duplicates (e.g. `ABC` and `AZC`). You can, of course, run a custom search on `myDict.Keys`, with the caveat that this is a linear search, not a constant-time key lookup. Optimizing that further is possible (create a new dictionary with `List<int>` values, based on equivalence classes) but that might be premature optimization if you're not doing this a lot.

Comment: @Jeroen is right as usual, because what hash code should a key with * yield? No matching hash means no Equals so it'll never be resolved.

Comment: `bool hasKey = myDict.Keys.Any(key => Regex.IsMatch(key, "A.C"));`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: Why have you deleted the answer? I guess this is what OP has asked for. Just add to the answer that the lookup performance is the same as a plain loop. It might be no problem if the dictionary is not huge and this search is an edge case. So it would be a good to first check if the search string contains the `*` char at all. Otherwise he can use `myDict.ContainsKey`

Comment: Ok, thanks for the replies. @DmitryBychenko this works to get the bool if exists. How to get the real value of the key? I assume that is better to create a List<string> instead, and then find the index/es that matches

Comment: @Jaume: use `Where` instead of `Any`, then you get all matches as `KeyValuePair<string, int>`. If you append `ToList` you get a `List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>` and you can check if `lis.Count > 0` fpor the `Any` and if you need the values you can access the `kv.Value`.

Comment: Do you know if the key only contains A-Z characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with a help of *Linq* and *Regular Expressions*. If keys consist of letters only

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

string pattern = "A*C";

bool hasKey = myDict
  .Keys
  .Any(key => Regex.IsMatch(key, pattern.Replace('*', '.')));
```

This is not an optimal approach as it linearly searches all keys in O(N), as opposed to the usual O(1) lookup.